# Using both SpamAssassin and postscreen in Postfix

Tags: spamassassin, postscreen

I'm trying to set up an MX server using Postfix, postscreen and SpamAssassin.

According to the SpamAssassin documentation, I have to add `-o content_filter` to the **smtp** service in **master.cf**.  This works with the default settings for Postfix, which is to use the `smtpd` command:

```
# SpamAssassin works:
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=spamd argv=/usr/local/bin/spamc -f -e  
  /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

But I also want  to use postscreen.  In order to use Postscreen,  the `smtpd` command has to be replaced with the `postscreen`  command. When I do that, postscreen works, but SpamAssassin stops working.

```
# SpamAssassin does not work:
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       postscreen
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=spamd argv=/usr/local/bin/spamc -f -e  
  /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

It appears that the `postscreen` command does not respect the `-o` flag? When I set `content_filter` in **main.cf** it works, but then I have to disable it for all other services than postscreen, that would get really messy in **master.cf** because i'd have to add `-o` to all other services.

---

What is the best way to use both postscreen and SpamAssassin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which documentation you use.
In my case, I have in the master file :

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
```

In the main.cf, I have :

```
postscreen_greet_action = enforce 
smtpd_milters = unix:/spamass/spamass.sock
```

So the mail is taken by postscreen, and if it pass it, go in spammassassin by using the milter.

Comment: I hadn't found `smtpd_milters`. That could be a good solution, because then I only need to override the submission service. I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: After trying a lot of different things, I found that the spamassassin socket is not the same as the spamass-milter socket. With that piece of information, setting up SpamAssassin was a breeze. Thank you :)